# Making a bluetooth device recognized as a COM port?

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth

**Backstory:**

So I have an HM10 (Bluetooth module) that is connected to my arduino. I have verified the connection with my phone by connecting to it and reading some packets so I am certain the connection to the arduino is solid. I have a usb Bluetooth module that is connected to my computer that has Windows 10 on it. I went into the settings on Windows, found the HM10, and connected to it no problem. It shows up as "connected" under my devices.  So the last part of the setup is to make the HM10 show up as a COM port. I have followed the instructions that many sites say:

1. Open Bluetooth Devices.
   Note From the Windows desktop, navigate: Start > (Settings) > Control Panel > (Network and Internet) > Bluetooth Devices.
   Note If using Windows 8/10, navigate: Right-click Start > Control Panel > In the search box, enter "Bluetooth" then select Change Bluetooth settings.
2. From the COM Ports tab, click Add.
3. Ensure that "Incoming (device initiates the connection)" is selected then click OK.
4. Click OK.

See how it is shown as connected in the bluetooth window:

[image]

Also see how it does show up in device manager:

[image]

**Problem:**

The problem that I have is even though my HM10 shows up in the valid Bluetooth devices under device manager, it does not show up in the list after I click "Incoming". The list is simply blank. Is there something I am missing to make it show up in this list?

[image]

Does not show up in this list!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was unable to directly figure out the problem however went a different route altogether. Since the goal of this question was to connect my Arduino to my computer wirelessly, I decided to use RF transmission instead of bluetooth. In doing this I purchased the following:

```
Qty    Item  
2      433 MHz Transciever that supports UART (or any frequency so long as both match)
1      USB to UART Converter
```

I believe that my biggest issue was that I did not have the USB to UART converter. This also may have been the reason my bluetooth modules didn't work as they were simply transcievers as well without the usb to UART converter. Either way, if someone else is trying to have wireless communication between an Arduino and a Windows based computer, I would suggest the RF method instead.

Answer (score 6):

I figured out that the problem is HM-10 and HM-11 do not have the "Standard Serial over Bluetooth link" function like HC-05 module, if anybody know how to add that function to it, it might work!

[HC-05 hardware functions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hH6X1.png)

[HM-11 hardware functions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrfdL.png)

if you have HC-05 bluetooth module, you can use it as direct UART connection to your computer without problem.

To open the hardware funtions windows: Control panel > Hardware and Sound > Devices and Printers > double click on the bluetooth device > choose Hardware tab.

Comment: This is also an acceptable answer as I discovered the real problem is like you said

Answer (score 0):

The [ble-serial](https://github.com/Jakeler/ble-serial) python tool may help. I have been succesfully used it for a HM-11 device, under Linux. But it can work for HM-10, under Windows, as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think shoud help:
[standard-serial-over-bluetooth-on-windows-10](https://community.element14.com/technologies/internet-of-things/b/blog/posts/standard-serial-over-bluetooth-on-windows-10)